# C/C++ Calculate and Collect Remainder

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am writing this on an Arduino so I don't believe the full scope of C or C++ is available to me, or is it?

I have a sequence of numbers being generated and I want to collect the value of the tens and units columns off of the end;

For example, if the first generated number were 8028, I would want to minus 28 from it and record 28. If the next number were 3479 I would want to take 79 off and store that with 28 (as a running total, so 107).

```
int number=0;
int remainder=0;
int runningTotal=0;
while (true) {
    number = random number between 1000 and 65,535;
    remainder = 10's units from number;
    number = number - remainder;
    runningTotal += remainder;
}
```

So I'm collecting a running total of anything less than one hundred on the end of the number.

Comment: The operator `%` calculates the remainder of its left argument divided by its right argument. That's what you want: `remainder = number % 100;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to use a **modulus** if you can, in c/c++ its the `%` operator:

```
8028 % 100 

3479 % 100
```

etc

Comment: Damn it, that was so obvious, why didn't I think of that! Still thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

`x % 100` will get you the remainder of dividing `x` by `100`, that is the last two base-10 digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
8028 / 100 => 80
8028 % 100 => 28
3479 / 100 => 34
3479 % 100 => 79
```

So division and modulus are all you need.